# Problema no servidor xampp

Tags: php, apache, xampp

Estou com um problema no servidor xampp, esta instalado em um linux, onde quando vou iniciar via terminal aparece a seguinte mensagem abaixo.

> tail: não foi possível abrir “/opt/lampp/logs/error.log” para leitura: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado

Cheguei a perceber que o apache da um erro e não inicia.

Comment: Crie o diretório `/opt/lampp/logs/` (se não existir), e certifique-se de que o usuário do apache tem permissão de escrita nele.

Comment: o diretorio ja esta criado, e dei permissao de leitura a todos usuarios na pasta

Comment: E tem um arquivo error.log dentro?

Comment: nao error.log nao!!! tem o error_log

Comment: Então experimente criá-lo (`touch error.log` dentro do diretório)... E novamente atenção às permissões.

Comment: bfavaretto o error.log resolveu, so que agora esta ocorrendo o seguinte erro..  "Last 10 lines of "/opt/lampp/logs/error_log":"

Comment: pessoal descobri o que estava errado, pois havia dois apache rodando juntos, bastou eu parar um ou excluir

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque é específica demais para que possa ajudar outros usuários com problema semelhante.

Answer (score 1):

Olha, vou te sugerir outra coisa, e não resolver o teu problema com o XAMPP...

O PHP vem com um servidor embutido ou seja, você não precisa usar o XAMPP se não quiser!! :D

`php -s localhost:7000`

(se não me engano é assim...) digite `php -h`
 para mais informações!!

Valeuu!! :D

Comment: o problema que preciso do xampp... mas mesmo assim vou testar o servidor do php

Comment: Bruno voce tem outra ideia??

Comment: cara você experimentou re-instalar o xampp ?

Comment: sim nao resolveu

Comment: ja mudei a porta do servidor mas nada me adiantou

Comment: Precisa ser o xampp? porque não intala manualmente oque precisa com apt-get?

Comment: O server embutido a partir do php5.4 não substitui os servidores como apache , iis, etc..

Comment: cheguei nesse erro  "Last 10 lines of "/opt/lampp/logs/error_log":"

Comment: pessoal descobri o que estava errado, pois havia dois apache rodando juntos, bastou eu parar um ou excluir.

Comment: Escreve a sua resposta em outra thread, e marca como correta para fechar o tópico! :D